# change the legend.y property on browser resize

Tags: css, svg, highcharts

we use the highchart control with Angular and bootstrap.
To adjust the vertical space between the chart and the legend (both are rendered by highchart as svg elements), we set the `y` property of the `legend` on page load (in the `controller`) like this:

```
$scope.chartContracts = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            marginBottom: 50
        },
        legend : {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: 0,
            y: 4,
```

Now in one of the Bootstraps layouts, the spacing (y) should be `-10` in stead of `4` because for some reason an extra spacing is added.

So it should be based on media query or something similar I guess?

The question is how to do this... I tried with css but I can't seem to style SVG elements (they are called `<g>`)?

Comment: Could you write, what parameters should change spacing to -10?

Comment: the min-width of the screen, like in bootstrap media query `@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check window width and then return correct value.

```
var wWidth = $(window).width(),
    value;

if(wWidth < 400) {
   value = 5;
} else {
   value = 10;
}
```

//scope

```
y: value
```

Comment: and how would I send this y value to the chartoptions?